# Rank of factors of zero product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $X$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $Y$ is an $n\times p$ matrix such that $XY=0$. What is the maximum value that the rank of $Y$ can take in terms of the rank of $X$?

I think that the answer is the rank of $X$ subtracted from $n$, and that it is related to null space, but I cannot find how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm{rank}(XY)\geqslant\mathrm{rank}(X)+\mathrm{rank}(Y)-n$ by [Frobenius inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#cite_ref-4).
Conversely, assume $r=\mathrm{rank}(X)=n-\mathrm{rank}(Y)$. Then, performing the Gauss elimination on the columns of $X$, we get a non-singular matrix $Y'$ such that $XY'$ has $n-r$ zero columns. The rest is easy.